# Include new column for WooCommerce Email Invoice Only

Tags: woocommerce, e-commerce, invoice

I want to include a new column for the customer invoice email for my woocommerce website. But I don't want the new column to be seen in other customer emails.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file `/woocommerce/templates/emails/customer-invoice.php` to a subfolder `/woocommerce/emails/` in your active theme.
The following line includes the template file `email-order-details.php`.

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );
```

You can replace this line by the content of the above mentioned file.
Here you can add an additional column header. To also add the column content replace the following part:

```
echo wc_get_email_order_items( $order, array(
    'show_sku'      => $sent_to_admin,
    'show_image'    => false,
    'image_size'    => array( 32, 32 ),
    'plain_text'    => $plain_text,
    'sent_to_admin' => $sent_to_admin,
) );
```

by the content of email-order-items.php and customize your columns here.

If you want make your live easier you can use my plugin [WP HTML Mail for WooCommerce](https://etzelstorfer.com/en/downloads/wp-html-mail-woocommerce/) and just click the + icon to add a column.